# AndroidでのSQlite使用時に新規でテーブルを追加した際のエラー

Tags: android, sqlite

色々なサイトを参考にさせて頂きつつSQliteを用いてデータベース構築を試しています。
一度テーブルを作成してデータベースにデータを入力、データベースから読み込みまで出来たのですが、新規にテーブルを追加するとアプリを削除してもコードを削除してもエラーが発生するようになりました。よろしければご教授お願いいたします。

**********成功時コード*********

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "NameCommentDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table person(" +
                "name text not null," +
                "comment text," +
                "time text," +
                ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

**********エラー時コード*********

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "NameCommentDB", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table person(" +
                "name text not null," +
                "comment text," +
                "time text," +
                ");");

        db.execSQL("create table oasis(" +
                "name text not null," +
                "comment text," +
                "time text," +
                ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

**********他クラスエラーメッセージ箇所********

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.building_event);
        MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper(this);


     ***   final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase(); ←
```

***********エラーメッセージ************

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Answer (score 1):

成功時コードで何故成功したのかは解りませんが、
`time text` の後の `,` が原因だと思います。
削除して試してみて下さい。

```
    db.execSQL("create table person(" +
            "name text not null," +
            "comment text," +
            "time text" +
            ");");
```

oasis の方も同様に。

Comment: ご指摘頂いた点を修正したところ無事動きました！凄く助かりました、ありがとうございます！